# mysql query issue with calculated fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select client transactions by means of generated by person.

It should show me all call back, appointment, sent email or any other status's count for particular agent (generated by id).

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_transaction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `generated_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `schedule_for_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `target_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`)
)
```

Query:

```
SELECT generated_by_id as agent_id, count(*) as call_backs
FROM client_transaction
WHERE transaction_type='CALL_BACK'
GROUP BY generated_by_id
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63d8a/1)

I have created query for one status. But, I need it for every status. And I also want to get agent name from other agent table. After getting all appropriate data, how can I left join with agent table?

Thanks.

Comment: please add the table structure for agent and with some data.

Comment: Put your code *in your question*, do not link offsite.

Comment: So the query you show works that way you want, but you want to understand how to group by transaction_type?

Comment: sorry for that. and thanks for edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add transaction_type as a field in your query, and apply another level of grouping on it:

```
SELECT
    generated_by_id AS agent_id,
    transaction_type,
    count(*) AS transaction_count
FROM client_transaction
GROUP BY generated_by_id, transaction_type
/* sort in some manner */
ORDER BY generated_by_id ASC, transaction_type ASC
```

An example of doing similar query with a join to an agent table might look like:

```
SELECT
    /* I am assuming field names on agent table
     * and am guessing you want to join to be able
     * to get something like agent name in this query
    */
    a.id AS `agent_id`,
    a.name AS `agent_name`,
    ct.transaction_type AS `transaction_type`,
    count(*) AS `transaction_count`
FROM agent AS a
LEFT JOIN client_transaction AS ct
    ON a.id = ct.generated_by_id
GROUP BY `agent_id`, `transaction_type`
/* sort in some manner */
ORDER BY `agent_id` ASC, `transaction_type` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need it for every status

Group by the transaction type.

```
SELECT generated_by_id as agent_id, transaction_type, count(*) as call_backs
FROM client_transaction
GROUP BY generated_by_id, transaction_type
```

> how can I left join with agent table?

With a `LEFT JOIN`.